# Surge doesn't react to me when I enter my password

Tags: surge.sh

I run "surge" command then it asks me for my email. So I type email and press enter. Then surge wants my password, but when I type my password and press enter, It doesn't react to me.

See the below image:

[image]

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: Same here. I think it's about the sanctions in some countries such as Iran. You can bypass it using a proxy or VPN.

Comment: @rezam Thanks Reza, but it doesn't work again, is it fixed for you with VPN? I use Psiphon

Comment: You can try to capture network information and see where is the problem

Answer (score -1):

password in cli is always hidden, just typing your password and enter, it will works